# Align checkboxes underneath spinners

Tags: android

I have the below linearlayout inside a large relative layout.  Right now trying to get checkbox to appear below the spinners. I've tried using "layout_below", but still not able to show checkboxes line up underneath these spinners.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title2"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/s3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D1"
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All elements inside your linear layout will appear horizontally aligned, since you have `android:orientation="horizontal"`

You have several alternatives:

Using another linearLayout like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/x"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        >
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/spinner_title2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/s3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
           />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="D1"
        android:id="@+id/d1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Or changing your LinearLayout to a RelativeLayout, and then using layout_below